# Include multiple columns with SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have one table that has 4 categories columns, the below returns the first one category_id. I have 3 others called category_id2, category_id3 and Category_id4.

```
$sql_ca = "SELECT * FROM tour_category ORDER BY sort";
                        $result_ca = mysql_query($sql_ca);
                        $categories = $Manager->fetchAssoc($result_ca);
                        if(!empty($categories)){ 
                            foreach($categories as $cat){

                                $sql_tour = "SELECT t.* FROM tour t  
                                WHERE 
                                     t.touronline = 'yes' 
                                    AND t.category_id = {$cat['id']}
                                    AND t.location_id = {$city['id']}
                                    and t.type = 'P'
                                ORDER BY t.tourcode                 
                                "; 
                                $result_tour = mysql_query($sql_tour);
                                $tours = $Manager->fetchAssoc($result_tour);
```

I have tried putting in

```
AND t.category_id, t.category_id2, t.category_id3,t.category_id4 = {$cat['id']}
```

But I just cant get this to work, any tips?

Comment: Use `= {$cat['id']}` for each column.

Comment: try to echo query and copy it and check it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a WHERE condition for each column.  If you want all category columns to match `$cat['id']` it would look like this:

```
WHERE 
    t.touronline = 'yes' 
    AND t.category_id = {$cat['id']}
    AND t.category_id2 = {$cat['id']}
    AND t.category_id3 = {$cat['id']}
    AND t.category_id4 = {$cat['id']}
    AND t.location_id = {$city['id']}
    AND t.type = 'P'
```

If you want any category column to match `$cat['id']` it would look like this:

```
WHERE 
    t.touronline = 'yes' 
    AND (t.category_id = {$cat['id']}
        OR t.category_id2 = {$cat['id']}
        OR t.category_id3 = {$cat['id']}
        OR t.category_id4 = {$cat['id']})
    AND t.location_id = {$city['id']}
    AND t.type = 'P'
```